# CameraOverlay problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera

when you add an overlay to the camera picker, does it disable zooming and flash? I seem to be having this problem on iOS 4.3.4 devices and it is the only thing I can think of. Tap to focus still works though.

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation:

> "You can use an overlay view to present a custom view hierarchy on top of the default image picker interface. The image picker layers your custom overlay view on top of the other image picker views and positions it relative to the screen coordinates. If you have the default camera controls set to be visible, incorporate transparency into your view, or position it to avoid obscuring the underlying content."

You make the default controls visible with this line

```
camera.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

Comment: The controls are visible, but I cannot tap them. When I tap to focus, the zoom controls pop up, but I cannot use them. It only seems to work in my beta version, but in the final one on the app store, it is the only thing that does not.

Comment: Does your overlay require touch interaction? If your overlay does not require user interaction, you could disable touches to the overlay view itself, allowing the touch event to pass through to the buttons. It is a clever hack around this situation.

Comment: Other than the work around I described above ^, there appears to be no other way as referenced in this stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240960/hide-uiimagepickercontrollersourcetypcecamera-toolbar-but-specific-buttons